# Tensorflow - Why I am getting resource exhausted error on CPU while training the model on GPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am training a model on GPU but I encounter to a problem. Even though it is trained on GPU, it causes CPU memory to blow up and finally it crashes after sometime, saying Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[64,80,80,2] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 by allocator.

It is trained on GPU(NVidia GeForce GTX1050).

```
# CUDA #
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0, 1"
assert tf.test.is_gpu_available()
assert tf.test.is_built_with_cuda()
```

Task Manager:(It fills the memory until it crashes, There is no lists, no arrays, no data that can fill the memory that much, tested and checked. Also monitored using a profiler)

[image]

[image]

tensorflow-gpu:2.10.1
cudatoolkit:11.2.2

Note: I had to reset my computer and install everything from scratch, this happened after that.

Comment: I suggest just reducing the batch size or the model size or buying another stick of RAM. It is probably happening because of the shared memory between cpu and gpu, in my opinion there is no easy software fix.

Comment: I have already tried reducing batch size or similar memory consuming stuffs, but it did not work. Behavior is the same, it crashes after some time. Strange thing is that same program was working fine just before I reset my computer. Versions and packages I installed were also as same as before.

Comment: Please verify if the GPU is set up properly in your system by following the steps mentioned in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#software_requirements) and have installed all the required software for GPU support in the exact path. Also, Please share the minimal reproducible code to replicate the error.